# Разбить каждый элемент списка на элементы в кортежи Python

Tags: python, map, lambda, tuple

у меня есть текст. Например, вот такой:

```py
text = ['Я', 'не', 'могу', 'решить', 'задачу']
```

необходимо через map lambda получить вот такое:

```py
[((я,1)), ((н,1),(e,1)), ((м,1), (о,1), (г,1), (у,1)), ((р,1), (е,1), (ш,1),(и,1),(т,1),(ь,1)), ((з,1), (а,2),(д,1),(ч,1),(у,1))
```

нужно получить список кортежей для каждого слова, где в каждом кортеже подсчитывается количество уникальных букв

Comment: в text ошибся. текст изначально список: ['Я', 'не', 'могу', 'решить', 'задачу']

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: x, text))`

Comment: такой не подходит?

Comment: не, не подходит

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: list(x), text))`

Comment: А такой подходит?

Comment: "также еще нужно вот такую задачу сделать: " - один вопрос - одна задача. Не нужно все ваши задачи в один вопрос собирать.

Comment: спасибо, @Peter_Kolosov. ваш ответ пригодился в другом задании по этому тексту

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Способ 1:**

```
import collections
res = list(map(lambda x: tuple(collections.Counter(x).items()), text))
```

покороче

```
import collections
res = [*map(lambda x: tuple(collections.Counter(x).items()), text)]
```

еще покороче

```
import collections
res = [tuple(collections.Counter(x).items()) for x in text]
```

и ещё

```
import collections
res = [(*collections.Counter(x).items(),) for x in text]
```

и в 1 строчку

```
res = [(*__import('collections').Counter(x).items(),) for x in text]
```

**Способ 2 (без внешних библиотек):**

сразу вариант покороче:

```
res = [tuple((l, x.count(l)) for i, l in enumerate(x) if l not in x[:i]) for x in text]
```

ну или подлиннее, но без `if`:

```
res = [tuple((l, x.count(l)) for l in sorted(set(x), key=lambda m: x.index(m))) for x in text]
```

или покороче, но для извращенцев:

```
res = [tuple((x[i], x.count(x[i])) for i in set(map(x.index, x))) for x in text]
```

**Способ 3 (если порядок букв не важен):**

```
res = [tuple((l, x.count(l)) for l in set(x)) for x in text]
```

если хочется на 1 байтик поменьше сделать и вообще не использовать `tuple`:

```
res = [(*((l, x.count(l)) for l in set(x)),) for x in text]
```

**Способ 4 (с использованием моржа):**

```
res = [(a := set(x), (*zip(a, map(x.count, a)),))[1] for x in text]
```

Answer (score 3):

Можете использовать `collections`:

```py
from collections import Counter

text = ['Я', 'не', 'могу', 'решить', 'задачу']

print(list(map(lambda x: tuple(Counter(x).items()), text)))
```

Comment: спасибо, @gord1402. ваш ответ помог, получилось как надо